# How to hide top navigation bar in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I want to hide top navigation bar in some cases.

this is not work in reactnavigation V4

```
  const RemoveTopBar = () => {
   navigation.setOptions({
           headerShown: () => false,
         });
}
```

how can i handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set like this.

```
navigation.setParams({ headerShown: false })}
```

you can check options in [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#updating-options-with-setoptions) with respect to any version by selecting version from here

[image]

Comment: you are right. However, it gives error that, "navigation.setOptions is not a function". Because it removed  in v4. What is alternative way ?

Comment: setOptions is available in v5, For v4 you can use setParams instead of setOptions

Comment: @hakan I added a guide on answer to check options related to your specific version.